# connection "sweetalert" method "confirm" and return values

Tags: javascript, callback, confirm, sweetalert

I have a problem with feedback function confirm

```
    sweetAlert: function() {
        window.legacyConfirm = window.confirm;

        window.confirm = function(msg, title, type, callback, params) {
            var title = (title == null) ? 'Warning!' : title;
            var test = 0;
            var type = (type == null) ? 'warning' : type;
            swal({
                    title: title,
                    text: msg,
                    type: type,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    allowEscapeKey: false,
                    allowOutsideClick: false
                }, function(isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {return true} else {return false}

            });
        };

    },
    removeItem: function(el) {
        var test;
        var $el      = $(this),
            _comfirm = $el.data('confirm') ? $el.data('confirm') : 'Remove product';
        if (confirm(_comfirm)) {
            console.log("OK")

        }
    }
```

removeItem method call to confirm that is declared in the method sweetAlert.

confirm always returns undefined and loop method removeItem is not called.

```
if (confirm(_comfirm)) {
    console.log("OK")
}
```

Comment: *"removeItem method call to confirm that is declared in the method sweetAlert."*, in the posted code where is the `sweetAlert` function called ?

Comment: method sweetAlert only to hold the "confirm". 

It is called at the bottom of the function: sweetAlert();

I use: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: `swal()` runs the callback function asynchronously. You can't return anything to the original caller.

Comment: how can I return value to method "confirm" ?